# A program in C to get previous two fibonacci numbers less than the given number

Tags: c, function, fibonacci

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibo(int);

int main() {
    int n, p[100];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int i = 0;
    do {
        p[i] = fibo(i);
        i++;
    } while (p[i] <= n);

    printf("%d %d", p[i-1], p[i]);

    return 0;
}

int fibo(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (fibo(i - 1) + fibo(i - 2));
    }
}
```

This is the program I have written. I got an utterly rubbish answer. Can someone help me with where I am going wrong?

Comment: `i++;
  } while(p[i] <= n);` your array index is already incremented when you check the latest value. (the same for `printf("%d %d", p[i-1], p[i]);` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize i=-1, and inside the `do while loop` increment i first

```
int i=-1;

do
{
    i++;
    p[i] = fibo(i);


  } while(p[i] <=n);


  printf("%d %d", p[i-1], p[i-2]);// print i-1 and i-2
```

The problem was when you check `p[i]<=n` with the original question's code posted, you are checking for garbage value since at that time i was already incremented.

Answer (score 2):

You compare the array element after the one you just computed.  The array is uninitialized, the behavior is undefined.

You can fix your code this way:

```
int main() {
    int n, p[100];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int i = 0;
    do {
        p[i] = fibo(i);
        i++;
    } while (p[i-1] <= n);

    printf("%d %d", p[i-2], p[i-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

However your code has several small issues:

- You do not check if `scanf()` succeeded.
- You do not check for potential buffer overflow when storing values to the `p` array.
- You have undefined behavior for small values of `n` as you will be reading entries of `p` at negative offsets.

Here is a corrected version that addresses these issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibo(int);

int main(void) {
    int n, p[100];

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            p[i] = fibo(i);
            if (p[i] > n)
                break;
        }
        if (i >= 2) {
            printf("%d %d\n", p[i - 2], p[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int fibo(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else
    if (i == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (fibo(i - 1) + fibo(i - 2));
    }
}
```

Note however that the Fibonacci sequence diverges quickly, and arithmetic overflow can occur, causing undefined behavior, producing an incorrect result for large values of `n`.

Here is simpler solution that does not use recursion and does not have this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, a = 0, b = 1;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 1) {
        while (a < n - b) {
            int c = a + b;  /* no overflow possible */
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```